# Create a vector function from a scalar function in R

Tags: r

Here is my function. It takes certain values on [-5,-3] and [3,5] and 0 elsewhere. The function is symmetric around the origin.

```
f<-function(x){
    y=0 
    if (x>=-5 && x<=-3){
        y=3*(1-(x+4)^2)/8
    }
    if (x>=3 && x<=5){
        y=3*(1-(x-4)^2)/8
    }
    return(y)
}
```

Okay so I used the function `sapply (bins, f)`

where `bins = seq(-5,5,by=0.05)`. This worked fine!

but when I tried to do f(bins), I got this ridiculous answer. It was correct for the [-5,-3] range.

My guess for this is that when the function f checked the first if condition, it checked it only for the first value of the bins vector, so for (-3,5] range, it incorrectly used the formula only intended for [-5,-3].

I am trying to get a way to draw a curve for these points, but when I used curve function, the curve is drawn using the wrong values we would get by using f(bins)

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Your guess is correct.  It would be clear if you used & rather than && above (a warning would be generated by the `if` statements).  Note that you must use & for the ifelse solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to [Vectorize](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Vectorize.html) the function `f` to get it to apply over a vector:

```
f = Vectorize(f)
print(f(bins))
```

Note that you could have also just used `curve` with `sapply`:

```
curve(sapply(x, f), from=-5, to=5)
```

Finally, if you wrote the function with `ifelse` like so:

```
f = function(x) {
    ifelse(x >= -5 & x <= -3, 3*(1-(x+4)^2)/8, ifelse(x>=3 & x<=5, 3*(1-(x-4)^2)/8, 0))
}
```

That would allow it to work on vectors without needing `Vectorize`.

Comment: I was just about to post the `ifelse` solution.  Yours has an error - the last 'else' value should be 0.

Comment: @DavidRobinson a quick additional question, maybe I should start a new post. would you be tell me how to overlay the plot of a function (like this one) on a histogram. I simulated from this distribution I just wrote up there and would like a graphical overlay of the pdf.

Comment: Include the `add=TRUE` argument to `curve`

Answer (score 3):

It would be a lot faster to write the function so it were entirely vectorized:

```
f <- function(x){  0 + (x >=-5 & x <= -3)*(3*(1-(x+4)^2)/8) +
                   + (x >= 3 & x <= 5)*( 3*(1-(x-4)^2)/8) }
```

And from the symmetry further simplification is possible (I think):

```
f <- function(x){  0 + ( abs(x) <= 5 & abs(x) >= 3)*( 3*(1-(abs(x) -4)^2)/8) }
```

Comment: This is very close to the `ifelse` solution, but I find it easier to read.